# Flow Error Occured "The flow failed to access the value for"

Tags: workflow, process-builder, process, app-builder

I am getting this flow error,while updating field in process builder:

This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.RecordType.Name because it hasn't been set or assigned..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the right-hand-side of this image would show that you're assigning the reference to the Record Type Name of that `SymphonyIPM__` record. This issue will occur when that object's Record Type is null, because in trying to reach the record type's name you're actually traversing a join:

```
(my object)->RecordType via RecordTypeId->Name
```

When `RecordTypeId` is `null`, this results in an exception.

This isn't actually the right way to assign an object's record type in Process Builder, however. Instead of assigning the Record Type Name, simply assign the `RecordTypeId` directly. That will work even if your source record has a null record type.